# Get feed of comments from Blogger blog

Tags: blogger

Given a particular blog on Blogger, how does one get a feed of ONLY the comments, specifically comments containing certain words? I thought it was by appending `feeds/comments/default`, but that returns only posts. How does one get them from before a specific date?

The `q` parameter does not seem to work for comments, too. As the returned data sometimes doesn't contain the searched-for word.

Comment: where's your [mcve]?